# Essential things to bring to the hospital

Tags: birth

What are the essential things to bring when going into the hospital to give birth?

I have a short list of things that I can remember the midwives mentioning, such as a hat and vests for the newborn and sanitary pads.

Comment: The mom to be comes to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a list based mostly on my experience... I've marked it as community wiki so others can add to it rather than accuumulating a lot of related similar answers.

**For pre-labour, for example if you are admitted for induction:**

- Nightgown (preferred over pyjamas for ease of access for monitoring!)
- Eyemask, earplugs (hard to sleep in hospital)
- Plenty of distraction activities (books, puzzles, knitting... whatever floats your boat)
- Enough clean clothes and underwear for at least a couple of days
- General toiletries

**For labour and birth:**

- A variety of energy-rich snacks (you don't know what you'll feel like eating)
- Water bottle
- MP3 player and appropriate choice of music
- Copy of birth plan
- Contact details for friends and family
- Camera
- Old or disposable nightgown (or large t-shirt) and underwear

**For you after the birth:**

- Nursing bra
- Comfortable clothes (still maternity clothes at this point)
- Old or disposable big pants
- Enormous maternity pads
- Shower stuff

**For baby:**

- Two or three vests / babygros / bodysuits
- Two or three sleepsuits
- Hat
- Newborn size nappies
- Wipes or a big bag of cotton wool
- Car seat (and instructions for use!) if you will be leaving by car